# error QTmultimedia in raspberry pi 3

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

i built **Qt5** on `raspberry pi 3`. but, when i compile example in `qtmultimedia`, i get notification:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I really fix this error.
Add a new line to /etc/ld.so.conf: <path to lib>
sudo ldconfig

Comment: Consider making this an answer and accepting it. Might help other people.